# Get date only from datepicker

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

How do I get only date eg : 2011-03-04 FROM A DATEPICKER in windows phone development environment in Visual studio for windows phone? thanks

Answer (score 4):

Let's say your DatePicker control is called MyDatePicker, just use this:

```cs
var dateOnly = MyDatePicker.Value.Value.Date;
```

Or do you mean the appearance of the date in the control per say?

If that is the case, you have the ValusStringFormat property of the DatePicker control, just set it to `{0:d}` or something like that (you can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) the standard datetime format strings)

Comment: Updated the answer, please check if that is what you need!

Answer (score 0):

var date = DatePicker1.Value.Value.Date;

```
        MessageBox.Show(date.ToShortDateString());
```

if u wants to get the time alone

```
        var date = DatePicker1.Value.Value.Date;
        MessageBox.Show(date.ToShortTimeString());
```